# Ar services stopped working after hyper os update

Tags: arcore

I have the Google play services for AR app installed on m'y POCO F5 and it was working before but stopped working after the hyper os update (Xiaomi.eu)

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the Google play services for AR app but it didn't work.

I use the depth lab app to test if it is working.